# Swift code to loop through the table custom cell rows

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for code in swift to loop through the table custom cell row (have 2 text boxes in row). These rows are dynamically created and on click of button, i want to read those text box values. I don't find good example for this in online, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't loop through the cells. You need to loop through your data model. The model contains the data. The view do not contain the data (the views just show data).

Comment: can you show some examples/links?

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is wrong. You should not store any data in table view cells. The user can scroll them off the screen at any time and any changes to the data is lost.

You should really store the input from your table view cells into your model as soon as the user makes a change.

Comment: I have updated my question with code snippet using model. can you please tell me where i am wrong now?